# With Prototype how do I disable autocomplete for a given input text box?

Tags: prototypejs

I am sure this is on here already...

I want to be able to disable autocomplete for some CMS generated form fields with some frontend javascript code, preferably Prototype but neat javascript will do if it has no cross-browser problems.

I have ids for my boxes and I am not using some clever 'prototype autocomplete' (that seems to stuff the Google results on this). Regular browser autocomplete is what I want to turn off and not for the entire form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knew I would find it as soon as I asked:

```
$$('.MacGuffin')[1].setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');

$$('.MacGuffin')[7].setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
```

That is specifying elements by class rather than id.